# My aws instance is stuck and cannot connect usign ssh what should i do

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ubuntu-16.04

My aws instance is stuck and cannot connect using ssh client what should i do?

My hosted websites are also not working. I do not want to restart my aws instance through aws console.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you don't want to restart using aws management console ?

Comment: i want connection using ssh to  debug and find the issue with the instance

Comment: were you able to do ssh earlier?

Comment: what is the type of instance you are using? Is it T series family?

Comment: i was already using MobaXterm for ssh access and it works fine when the instance is working .

Answer (score 3):

### A recommendation to troubleshoot these kinds of problems

> - Always generate logs.
> - Always use a Cloudwatch's agent to retrieve specific logs from your instances.
> - **Check this link to learn more about it:** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/send_logs_to_cwl.html

### About your problem

- I think you tried to connect to it via SSH too many times without closing the previous connections.
- Your instance is out of memory, for this situation you must restart your instance.
- You could get the last screenshot of your instance using the options from Console.

[image]

### Follow this link for more information about troubleshooting

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html

**Some suggestions from that link:**

- Check your security group rules. You need a security group rule that allows inbound traffic from your public IPv4 address on the proper port.
- [EC2-VPC] Check the route table for the subnet. You need a route that sends all traffic destined outside the VPC to the internet gateway for the VPC.
- [EC2-VPC] Check the network access control list (ACL) for the subnet. The network ACLs must allow inbound and outbound traffic from your local IP address on the proper port. The default network ACL allows all inbound and outbound traffic.
  -If your computer is on a corporate network, ask your network administrator whether the internal firewall allows inbound and outbound traffic from your computer on port 22 (for Linux instances) or port 3389 (for Windows instances).

*And more...*

Answer (score 0):

If the issue still continues, please create an AMI(image) of the instance and try to create a new instance from that AMI. Then try to SSH and everything went smooth the terminate the old instance.